# JMeter Console : Summary of the Test Plan

Tags: jmeter

I am just two days old in using `JMeter`. I have been asked (at the current scenario) to use the `console` to run `Test Plans`. I have been able to generate the logs in the console. Now, what I am required to show in the log is a `Summary Report` something like that of the `GUI`. I tried using the `summariser` of `JMeter` but didn't get the exact results (may be because I don't know how to use it exactly).

I want the following in the summary:

`Average Response Time`

`Min Response Time`

`Maximum Response Time`

`Standard Deviation`

`Error%`

`Throughput`

`KB/sec`

`Average Bytes`

These have to be shown for `each HTTP Request` present in the `Test Group`. I have been working around to get through this for about a day or so. But, am unable to do so.

Please guide me along this. Is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD like this:

```
java -jar CMDRunner.jar --tool Reporter --generate-csv test.csv --input-jtl results.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

Then you'll have test.csv containing your test summary data.

Answer (score -1):

You can generate Stunning HTML report using Jmeter

For this use below commands to run jmeter through command prompt

```
jmeter -n -t \path to jmx file -l \location to csv file -e -o \location for html report
```

After running completed you can see the html report generated in the folder you have mentioned